# Elixir - Phoenix - function :erl_posix_msg.message/1 is undefined

Tags: erlang, elixir, phoenix-framework, gen-server, beam

I have two server running a pretty simple Phoenix framework API and every week or so, one of the servers starts throwing 502 errors.

```
15:35:08.260 [error] 'File operation error: emfile. Target: /usr/lib/erlang/lib/stdlib-3.2/ebin/erl_posix_msg.beam. Function: get_file. Process: code_server.'

15:35:08.323 [error] 'File operation error: emfile. Target: erl_posix_msg.beam. Function: get_file. Process: code_server.'

15:35:08.324 [error] GenServer #PID<0.6569.17> terminating
** (UndefinedFunctionError) function :erl_posix_msg.message/1 is undefined (module :erl_posix_msg is not available)
    (stdlib) :erl_posix_msg.message(:emfile)
    (redix) lib/redix.ex:393: Redix.format_error/1
    (redix) lib/redix/connection.ex:108: Redix.Connection.connect/2
    (connection) lib/connection.ex:622: Connection.enter_connect/5
    (stdlib) proc_lib.erl:247: :proc_lib.init_p_do_apply/3
Last message: nil
State: %Redix.Connection{backoff_current: nil, opts: [socket_opts: [], sync_connect: false, backoff_initial: 500, backoff_max: 30000, log: [disconnection: :error, failed_connection: :error, reconnection: :info], exit_on_disconnection: false, host: "redis.host.not", port: 6379], receiver: nil, shared_state: nil, socket: nil}

15:35:08.324 [error] Ranch protocol #PID<0.6568.17> (:cowboy_protocol) of listener Auth.Endpoint.HTTP terminated
** (exit) an exception was raised:
    ** (UndefinedFunctionError) function :erl_posix_msg.message/1 is undefined (module :erl_posix_msg is not available)
        (stdlib) :erl_posix_msg.message(:emfile)
        (redix) lib/redix.ex:393: Redix.format_error/1
        (redix) lib/redix/connection.ex:108: Redix.Connection.connect/2
        (connection) lib/connection.ex:622: Connection.enter_connect/5
        (stdlib) proc_lib.erl:247: :proc_lib.init_p_do_apply/3
```

If I just restart phoenix server, boom, everything starts working again. Obviously this isn't a scalable solution, but I'm struggling to diagnose what's going on.

Any help would be sweet.

Thanks

Comment: `emfile` = `too many files open` (http://blog.izs.me/post/56827866110/wtf-is-emfile-and-why-does-it-happen-to-me). Something is leaking file descriptors most likely and it's hitting the number of open files limit after a week.

Comment: Good point, you're not wrong. So I ran: `ulimit -a` and for this

...
open files (-n) 1024
...

I then ran: lsof -i -n -P | wc -l`

To get total connections open (99% to Redis). The result was 1028. So that's definitely the problem. So the next question is why is Elixir/Phoenix not killing file descriptors.

Comment: Can you post the code(s) where you're creating Redix instances? Maybe they're not being closed for some reason or you're creating too many instances.

Comment: So I'm using [Redix](https://github.com/whatyouhide/redix) and I have a pretty simple module that looks like this:

https://gist.github.com/jakowicz/7c46bfcdd16216322d844f63183b8a61

The get_conn method is being run by a plug before every controller and the kill_conn method is being run by our response module and I've used logs to guarantee that the connection kill is definitely being run.

Comment: You have only ~1000 extra connections after a week. Maybe `kill_conn` is not being in some edge cases?

Comment:   This is a new API that is still be tested, it's not actually in production yet. Sometimes it only takes a few days, it depends how much testing we're doing. I have [lsof](https://gist.github.com/jakowicz/ddb0f39eab51a4df91e0f60453dec552) running on loop and the Redis connections are going up by 1 on every request to the API. I'm using Redix v0.4.0, so I'm going to try v0.6.0. Oddly this doesn't seem to happen on OSX, but does on any CentOS machine.

Comment: Ok, so I've updated to 0.6.0 and I no longer have leaking processes. Hooray, thanks for the support Dogbert.

Answer (score 1):

Reading the [OTP erl_posix_msg](https://github.com/blackberry/Erlang-OTP/blob/3ec06ce97019eed9472a2cf8950ed23d7a2e6b9b/lib/stdlib/src/erl_posix_msg.erl#L90) module you can see that it is code for "too many open files".

```erlang
message_1(emfile) -> <<"too many open files">>;
```